# Filtering column dropdown lists on datatable intialisation

Tags: jquery, authentication, datatables

I have a datatable of rows, each with a checkbox, that need to be authenticated according to customer.  I've so far been running authentication immediately after datatable intialisation, and all has worked very well, ie  non-valid rows are nicely greyed-out and their checkboxes disabled.  Now I want to add individual column filters in the datatable.  I've got this to work, but the problem is that the dropdown lists show elements from ALL rows, instead of just from the authenticated rows.  I'm guessing that I need to authenticate the datatable during intialisation instead of after, as this will allow me to append each option value using a filter or an if statement of some sort.  But I can't think of a way to access the table to authenticate it, before it's initialised.  I think I'm now in a state of utter confusion because of my inexperience.  All I really want to achieve is authenticated (ie filtered) dropdown lists in each column. Any guidance very much appreciated.  I've simplified the code in a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmgwyw9z/

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>


<div id="TradeCodesPopupProductsCodesStore_tr">
  <form id="frm-example" action="/nosuchpage" method="POST">

    <table id="example" class="display select" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Clicks</th>
      <th>Trading Code</th>
      <th>Product Group</th>
      <th>Product description</th>
    </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr id="row250200">
          <td><input id="HS250200" type="checkbox" value="HS 250200" /></td>
          <td> 250200 </td>
          <td> Raw Materials </td>
          <td> Iron Ore - unroasted </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row260111">
          <td><input id="HS260111" type="checkbox" value="HS 260111" /></td>
          <td> 260111 </td>
          <td> Raw Materials - Iron ore </td>
          <td> Iron Ore - fines, concentrate, lump </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row730490" class="TypeCarbon_Alloy">
          <td><input id="HS730490" type="checkbox" value="HS 730490" /></td>
          <td> 730490 </td>
          <td> Pipe &amp; tube - Seamless </td>
          <td> Seamless tube - other </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row730512" class="TypeCarbon_Alloy">
          <td><input id="HS730512" type="checkbox" value="HS 730512" /></td>
          <td> 730512 </td>
          <td> Pipe &amp; tube - Welded </td>
          <td> Welded tube - line pipe, LW, >406.4mm </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row730230" class="TypeCarbon_Alloy_Stainless">
          <td><input id="HS730230" type="checkbox" value="HS 730230" /></td>
          <td> 730230 </td>
          <td> Longs </td>
          <td> Railway Materials </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row721921" class="TypeStainless">
          <td><input id="HS721921" type="checkbox" value="HS 721921" /></td>
          <td> 721921 </td>
          <td> Flats - HR plate </td>
          <td> HR plate - discrete or CTL, >10mm </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </form>
</div>
```

.

```
$(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable({

    orderCellsTop: true,
    scrollY: '50vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,

    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns([1, 2, 3]).every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select><option value="">Show all</option></select>')

          .appendTo($(column.header()))
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );

            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        // Create dropdown lists
        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });

      });
    }
  });

  // -------------------

  // Default:  Disable all rows
  $('#example td input').prop("disabled", true).closest('tr').css({
'color': '#dcdcdc'
  }).find(':checkbox').hide();

  // Authenticate relevant rows only
  $("#HS260111, #HS730512, #HS730230").prop("disabled", false).closest('tr').css({
'color': 'black'
  }).find(':checkbox').show();

});
```

Comment: curious: why do you need/want to eliminate those options from the dropdowns? even if they are available there, the corresponding rows are grayed out, is it really worth the extra code, or is it a requirement?

Comment: There could be up to 260 trade codes, with say 5 authenticated ones.  Ploughing through that lot would be cumbersome and heavy I'd have thought

Comment: fair enough, so what you need is to eliminate an option from a dropdown if at least one row with that option's text in its corresponding column is grayed out, correct?

Comment: Exactly!  Ideally after initialisation, but not sure if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things first:

1. Had to move `// Default:  Disable all rows` and `// Authenticate relevant rows only` to the beginning of the function, because I needed the rows already grayed out for my code to work. I don't think it broke anything.
2. Added class `grayed-out` to grayed out rows.

Now the real deal:

To filter which `option` tags were appended and which not, I added `if(rowsLetMe(i, d))` just before `select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')`. The function will check every grayed out `tr` and within it, all `td`s corresponding to the column of the `select` being inspected.

**Bonus feature :)**

Every time I clicked a `select` tag, the event would bubble up to its parent and would trigger the row-ordering function, which (I think) was not expected behaviour. Hence:

```
.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[very useful](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

Almost there, one last thing: **this code needs refactoring for efficiency, it is just a working example of how you could go about it**.

Try it and let me know: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmgwyw9z/55/

### EDIT REGARDING YOUR DOUBTS

### e.stopPropagation()

You should check the link I provided for a more comprehensive explanation but, in essence:

adding this line to a handler (for click events in this case) will *stop* the event from *propagating* up the DOM tree. In your example I included it because I noticed what I thought was undesired behavior: every time I would hit a `<th>` tag, whether or not I was clicking specifically on it or on the `<select>` tag it contained, a reordering of the table was executed, this meant:

- One click for expanding the `<select>` -> reordering executed
- Another click for selecting an option -> reordering executed

Event propagation works from the innermost element to the outermost one, an image is worth a thousand words:

[image: event bubbling]

and some code is worth a million:

```js
function highlight(elem) {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'
  alert(elem.className)
  elem.style.backgroundColor = ''
}
```

```css
div{
position: absolute;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: green;
}

div div{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background: blue;
left: 50px;
top: 50px
}

div div div{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
left: 50px;
top: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="d1" onclick="highlight(this)">1
  <div class="d2" onclick="highlight(this)">2
    <div class="d3" onclick="highlight(this)">3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, there is a lot more to it, so do a deeper research on the subject, it can really be a lifesaver.

### Refactoring

> Code refactoring is the process of restructuring existing computer code—changing the factoring—without changing its external behavior. Refactoring improves nonfunctional attributes of the software. [More...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)

I just meant that you should not leave the `rowsLetMe(i, d)` function as is, it works but it is not efficient (if you care for/need such a thing), maybe cache some selectors like the table rows for instance, so `$('table tbody tr.grayed-out')` does not query the DOM on each call to the method, stuff like that. In short: change (improve) how it does it, not what it does.

Comment: Echevarria this is really impressive and it works perfectly.  As far as my research can tell, it's the very first example of authenticating column dropdown lists for a datatable I've seen anywhere.  I've learned much from your very clear explanations, but I have 2 questions: Might I run into problems in other parts of my code from using  e.stopPropagation() ?   Also, please explain 'refactoring' as I haven't heard of this. Is it about achieving a better 'logical flow' of the code?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Great explanations and all in a not too technical language that I actually understand(!)  I'm already on the case of further researching this. Great stuff.